# Is code easily portable between Cortex A5 and Cortex A9 made by two different companies?

Tags: c, arm

Can code written for an Cortex A5 built by one company be ported to a Cortex A9 made by another company without too much difficulty?

I want to write some bare metal C code that runs on Atmel's [SAMA5D4](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/arm/sama5.aspx#SAMA5D4_series) (Cortex A5) that takes video from a CMOS camera with a parallel interface and encodes it to H.264. That chip can hardware encode at 720p.

Later, I may want to build a similar setup that can encode at 1080p, so I would want to upgrade to a more expensive chip, NXP [i.MX 6Solo](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/arm-processors/i.mx-applications-processors/i.mx-6-processors/i.mx-6solo-processors-single-core-multimedia-3d-graphics-arm-cortex-a9-core:i.MX6S) (Cortex A9).

So I want to know if I would encounter major headaches or if it would be rather easy to port later. My gut tells me it should be easy but I thought I'd better ask the experts first. If it's a huge headache though I may start with the more expensive chip first.

I'm new to this and not at all experienced with ARM chips or even much C but am willing to learn :-)

Comment: Do you realize how many variables your equation has?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. If your code is pure C (no inline assembler) then I don't see why you should have problems, the C compiler would generate correct code for the Cortex A9 (provided you have a C compiler that supports the Cortex A9.

Comment: @Pablo I would imagine the code, even in a pure C (which is rarely possible with embedded systems) will make some HW-specific registers.

Comment: @Eugene that's the point of the compiler, so you don't have to worry about these things. In general with pure C Code and with a C compiler for the target, you'll get a running program.

Comment: @Pablo Just curious, have you ever programmed a bare-metal embedded target?

Comment: Yes I have, for my thesis at the university I did write an RTOS for the gumstix, 95% C Code, the rest assembler.

Comment: @Pablo So I guess it involved some timers at the very least. So how will you deal with timers portably?

Comment: @Eugene: For code where I don't need to execute specific commands or in an specific order, I used plain C and let the compiler do the rest. When I had to write to a device, let's say interrupt controller @0x40d00000 I declared `#define __REG(x)    (*((volatile uint32_t *) x))` and then `#define ICIP __REG(0x40d00000)`. Afterwards I just used `ICIP = SOME_VAL;`. The compiler generates the best code for writing at location 0x40d00000. If other ARM architectures have ICIP in the same location, the the code would be portable.

Comment: So now reread your last statement. Why do you think it will be at the same location? Why do you think this periferal will even be there? At this very moment I am working with Cortex-A5 having a completely different interrupt controller.

Comment: For pieces of code where I have to call an specific command and/or in specific order (memory mappings for example), I would use inline assembler or an assembler file altogether. That is obviously not necessarily portable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147407/discussion-between-pablo-and-eugene-sh).

Comment: :37774253 I don't know, I would have to read the CPU manual. The best way to deal with that is to write code that is modular. Everything can be written purely in C, write it in C. Everything else you should put it on a different folder. At the end the you'll link all pieces together.

Comment: I used a similar way Linux manages the code. The machine independent code (aka pure C) was in the folder `kernel/...`. The machine dependent code in `arch/arm/pxa/kernel/...`. Note that I could have more than one architecture there. It is while linking when you decide which pieces of hardware dependent code you are going to include.

Comment: Which is bringing us to my second comment. I don't deny that the code can be well separated into platform dependent and portable parts. This is one of the variables I was talking about in the first comment.

Comment: Well, then I don't quite understand what you are asking. The only way to know if the code could be ported easily is to check the manuals of both CPUs and find the differences.

Comment: @Pablo You do realize I am not the OP, right?

Comment: Oops, no I haven't. Ok, that explains why I was confused.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I am the OP and no I didn't realize how many variables there might be. I tried to clearly state the use case so as to eliminate as many variables as possible. Given two similar processors from two different manufacturers is there expected to be significant effort required to copy some code that makes use of two hardware ports and one internal hardware function? Or should it be relatively straightforward e.g. rename some function calls. You can even ignore the hardware encoder function and just state from your experience yes, these processors have similar internals.

Comment: @Pablo thank you for your comments, if you're implying what I think you're implying it looks like porting between processors should not be a headache. Write it up as an answer.

Comment: @SlowBro It is *very* depending on how the code is written. If it is written cleanly, as Pablo described, separating the generic code from the processor specific - the effort is to only port the the processor specific stuff. Still some work, but doable. But unfortunately it is often not the case, and some platform specific stuff and hacks and workarounds are stuck here and there.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Got it. Write it up as an answer and I'll vote. Most helpful.

Comment: @SlowBro there is not a definite answer, as this depends on many factors and your question is so vague  that it is difficult to say anything definitive. Portability among similar families of CPUs is not that difficult, but it also depends on the code base you are using.

Comment: Well how can I clarify the question so that it is answerable?

Answer (score 0):

As captured in the comments, this task can be made easier if the code is initially written to attempt to clearly abstract the platform specific detail from the application code. This is not as simple as simply replacing the boot.s and isn't something that you can really claim to have done until you've tested the porting.

Much of the architectural behaviour between the two processors will be unchanged, and the C-compiler ought to be able to take advantage of micro-architectural optimisations. This optimisation may not be the best that you could achieve with some manual effort.

Where you are likely to see hard problems is any points in your code that are sensitive to memory ordering or potentially interactions between code and exceptions. The Cortex-A9 is significantly more out-of-order than the Cortex-A5, and the migration may expose bugs in your code. Libraries ought to be stable now, but there is still a risk to be aware of.   Anticipating this sort of problem is quite hard and if you are writing the majority of the code yourself you probably need to build in some contingency for the porting task. Once the code is stable on A9, issues of this sort are less likely to show up on either A5 (to give a lower cost production option), or more recent high performance cores.

Answer (score 0):

If I cut and paste a chapter of my math textbook into a my biology text book will that make sense?  They both are written using the english language.

No that makes no sense.  Assuming you are sticking to common ARM instructions for the code (english), the code isnt going to work from one chip (math book) to another (biology).  The majority of the difference is between the vendors logic which is outside the ARM core, no reason whatsoever to assume that two vendors have the same peripherals at the same addresses that work exactly the same bit for bit, gate for gate.

So in general baremetal will NOT work and does NOT work like this.  A very high level printf this or that C program, sure because you have many layers of abstraction including the target, doesnt even have to be arm to arm.  Now saying that it is certainly possible for you to make or maybe if very lucky find a hardware abstraction layer that hides the differences between the chips, at that layer then you can ideally write that portion of the project and port it.  As far as the arm vs arm the differences should be handled by the compiler and again dont even have to be arm to arm could be arm to mips.  Any assembly language you may have or any core specific accesses/instructions would need to be checked against the two technical reference manuals to insure they are compatible.  Probably not at the cortex-a level but for cortex-ms there are some address space core specific items that can affect high level language code, but for something like this to work you would have to hide that in the abstraction layer.

Generally NO, ARM is the underlying core, the chip differences have nothing to do with ARM so its like cutting and pasting a chapter from a mystery novel you are writing in english into a biography you are also writing in english and hoping that chapter makes sense in the latter book.